# Move value left if field is empty for a lot of columns

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have data as shown below representing the cheapest vendors listed from 1 to 10 along with their prices for a specific item (1 item/ware for each row).

Edit: I've used the below steps to reduce the data to the vendors I want to look at. Now I would like to move all the data left, so that I only have 6 columns with names/price of the vendor (instead of the 20 columns I have now).

Multiple Iif statements `(Iif(1_firma = "Computersalg" Or 1_firma = "Proshop" Or 1_firma = "Compumail";1_firma;"")`in column header, so now I only have data for the three vendors and their prices.

Current table columns and field (continues on for 10 vendors and prices eg. 20 columns in all):

```
+-----------+------------+--------+------------------+--------+------------------+--------+
|  ItemID   |  1_firma   | 1_pris |     2_firma      | 2_pris |     3_firma      | 3_pris |
+-----------+------------+--------+------------------+--------+------------------+--------+
| F20224236 |            |        |                  |        |                  |        |
| F974711   |            |        |                  |        | CompuMail        |     10 |
| 621893    |            |        | ComputerSalg A/S |     10 |                  |        |
| 107886    | CompuMail  |     10 |                  |        |                  |        |
| 575788    |            |        | CompuMail        |     10 | ComputerSalg A/S |     10 |
| 243652    | CompuMail  |     10 |                  |        |                  |        |
| 752734    |            |        | ComputerSalg A/S |     10 | CompuMail        |     10 |
| 717978    | CompuMail  |     10 |                  |        |                  |        |
| 885373    |            |        |                  |        | CompuMail        |     10 |
| F12973464 | Proshop.dk |     10 |                  |        |                  |        |
| 960583    | CompuMail  |     10 |                  |        |                  |        |
| 960581    |            |        | Proshop.dk       |     10 |                  |        |
| F12973605 |            |        |                  |        |                  |        |
| F1486274  |            |        | ComputerSalg A/S |     10 | Proshop.dk       |     10 |
| F487567   |            |        | CompuMail        |     10 |                  |        |
| 713000    | CompuMail  |     10 | Proshop.dk       |     10 | ComputerSalg A/S |     10 |
| 984712    |            |        |                  |        | CompuMail        |     10 |
+-----------+------------+--------+------------------+--------+------------------+--------+
```

Desired output:

```
+-----------+------------------+--------+------------------+--------+------------------+--------+
|  ItemID   |     1_firma      | 1_pris |     2_firma      | 2_pris |     3_firma      | 3_pris |
+-----------+------------------+--------+------------------+--------+------------------+--------+
| F20224236 |                  |        |                  |        |                  |        |
| F974711   | CompuMail        |     10 |                  |        |                  |        |
| 621893    | ComputerSalg A/S |     10 |                  |        |                  |        |
| 107886    | CompuMail        |     10 |                  |        |                  |        |
| 575788    | CompuMail        |     10 | ComputerSalg A/S |     10 |                  |        |
| 243652    | CompuMail        |     10 |                  |        |                  |        |
| 752734    | ComputerSalg A/S |     10 | CompuMail        |     10 |                  |        |
| 717978    | CompuMail        |     10 |                  |        |                  |        |
| 885373    | CompuMail        |     10 |                  |        |                  |        |
| F12973464 | Proshop.dk       |     10 |                  |        |                  |        |
| 960583    | CompuMail        |     10 |                  |        |                  |        |
| 960581    | Proshop.dk       |     10 |                  |        |                  |        |
| F12973605 |                  |        |                  |        |                  |        |
| F1486274  | ComputerSalg A/S |     10 | Proshop.dk       |     10 |                  |        |
| F487567   | CompuMail        |     10 |                  |        |                  |        |
| 713000    | CompuMail        |     10 | Proshop.dk       |     10 | ComputerSalg A/S |     10 |
| 984712    | CompuMail        |     10 |                  |        |                  |        |
+-----------+------------------+--------+------------------+--------+------------------+--------+
```

Comment: Concatenate the 10 fields or perhaps use a UNION query or even better, normalize data structure.

Comment: @June7 How would a unionquery work on the above data? I thought that was only for multiple queries/tables to be joined? All of the data is in the same table but different columns, is a union query still applicable here then? Can Access concatenate without writing up some VBA code?

Comment: A UNION query can rearrange multiple fields to a single field. The rearrangement would be a more normalized structure data should be in first place. Concatenation would be with an expression in query: `Field1 & "," + Field2 & "," + Field3 …`. Suggest your IIf() expression return a Null instead of " ". Then the + character will concatenate but if field is Null, will return Null instead of just a comma. However, I don't see how concatenation could arrange from cheapest to most expensive.

Comment: @June7 Thanks for the explanation, but wouldn't this just put all the data from the three vendors in one column though? What I needed is moving the data left but still as 3 separate columns. The current way of reading it from left to right is actually the rank of cheapest-->most expensive.

Comment: Non-normalized table structure does present a challenge for what you want to accomplish. Concatenation would result in one column of comma separated values. A UNION query could normalize data structure then that query could be used as source for subsequent queries, perhaps a CROSSTAB. Why are there no values in pris fields? It is considered best to post sample data as text table, not image, so that readers can copy/paste data.

Comment: @June7 Took a few tries with the formatting, but hope the table is usable. I will recieve a dataset like the above once a week (that isn't normalized at all as you clearly stated). I had removed the pris fields, as it showed price, but have just put in a random number in the table.

Comment: I have been testing some data I mocked up. This is challenging even with normalized structure. About reached the point where I would resort to VBA and temp table. The queries I have tested so far are very slow. I assume there are fields like ItemID and/or ItemDesc?

Comment: @June7 Thanks for taking the time to work with this! Yes, there is an ItemName which is the only unique feature. It's one of those things that is easy to do in via a manual excel based approach, but very hard to automate in access it appears. Even if a query takes a minute or two (perhaps even 5 minutes), it's okay if the end result is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got something to work but might be terribly slow with large dataset.

Normalized structure would have one pair of Firma and Pris fields. Your desired output can be accomplished by pivoting two sets of data via CROSSTAB. One CROSSTAB can be used by putting Firma and Pris values in 1 field. First step is to rearrange fields with UNION query.

Query1: DataUNION

```
SELECT ItemID, 1 AS Rank, [1_firma] AS Data, [1_firma] AS Vendor, "Firma" AS Category FROM Table1
UNION SELECT ItemID, 2, [2_firma], [2_firma], "Firma" FROM Table1
UNION SELECT ItemID, 3, [3_firma], [3_firma], "Firma" FROM Table1
UNION SELECT ItemID, 4, [4_firma], [4_firma], "Firma" FROM Table1
UNION SELECT ItemID, 5, [5_firma], [5_firma], "Firma" FROM Table1
UNION SELECT ItemID, 6, [6_firma], [6_firma], "Firma" FROM Table1
UNION SELECT ItemID, 7, [7_firma], [7_firma], "Firma" FROM Table1
UNION SELECT ItemID, 8, [8_firma], [8_firma], "Firma" FROM Table1
UNION SELECT ItemID, 9, [9_firma], [9_firma], "Firma" FROM Table1
UNION SELECT ItemID, 10, [10_firma], [10_firma], "Firma" FROM Table1
UNION SELECT ItemID, 1, [1_pris], [1_firma], "Pris" FROM Table1
UNION SELECT ItemID, 2, [2_pris], [2_firma], "Pris" FROM Table1
UNION SELECT ItemID, 3, [3_pris], [3_firma], "Pris" FROM Table1
UNION SELECT ItemID, 4, [4_pris], [4_firma], "Pris" FROM Table1
UNION SELECT ItemID, 5, [5_pris], [5_firma], "Pris" FROM Table1
UNION SELECT ItemID, 6, [6_pris], [6_firma], "Pris" FROM Table1
UNION SELECT ItemID, 7, [7_pris], [7_firma], "Pris" FROM Table1
UNION SELECT ItemID, 8, [8_pris], [8_firma] ,"Pris" FROM Table1
UNION SELECT ItemID, 9, [9_pris], [9_firma], "Pris" FROM Table1
UNION SELECT ItemID, 10, [10_pris], [10_firma], "Pris" FROM Table1;
```

Query2: DataUNION_Filtered

```
SELECT DataUNION.ItemID, DataUNION.Rank, DataUNION.Data, DataUNION.Vendor, DataUNION.Category
FROM DataUNION
WHERE Vendor="Computersalg" Or Vendor = "Proshop" Or Vendor = "Compumail";
```

Query3: DataCROSSTAB

```
TRANSFORM First(DataUNION_Filtered.Data) AS FirstOfData
SELECT DataUNION_Filtered.ItemID
FROM DataUNION_Filtered
GROUP BY DataUNION_Filtered.ItemID
PIVOT [Category] & DCount("*","DataUNION_Filtered", 
              "ItemID='" & [ItemID] & "' AND Rank<" & [Rank] & " AND Data<>Vendor")+1
              In ("Firma1","Pris1","Firma2","Pris2","Firma3","Pris3");
```

If you want filter criteria in Query2 to be dynamic (and for more info on CROSSTAB query), review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-67.html#Param

However, items that do not have data for selected vendors will not be in the CROSSTAB output. Join the CROSSTAB to a table of all items in a fourth query. I suppose your original table could serve that purpose.

```
SELECT Table1.ItemID, Firma1, Pris1, Firma2, Pris2, Firma3, Pris3
FROM DataCROSSTAB RIGHT JOIN Table1 ON DataCROSSTAB.ItemID = Table1.ItemID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create n-queries from your first table.

```
SELECT ItemID, 1_firma AS x_firma, 1_pris AS x_Pris, "1_firma" As FirmaName FROM Talbe WHERE 1_firma Is Not Null  'qry1
SELECT ItemID, 2_firma AS x_firma, 2_pris AS x_Pris, "2_firma" As FirmaName FROM Talbe WHERE 2_firma Is Not Null  'qry2
SELECT ItemID, 3_firma AS x_firma, 3_pris AS x_Pris, "3_firma" As FirmaName FROM Talbe WHERE 3_firma Is Not Null ' qry3
And so on...
```

Then `Union`them:

```
SELECT * FROM qry1 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM qry2 UNION ALL SELECT * FROM qry3
```

This should be the fastest way.

This way you would get `575788` and other keys twice. 
To distinguish you have the flag with the firm name.

**Update**

This is an alternative approach, which has a better data model and you can do all the same like in your descriped desired output.

The Final result will look like this:

```
 ItemID    x_firma           x_pris   FirmaName
F974711   CompuMail            10      1_firma
621893    ComputerSalg A/S     10      1_firma
575788    CompuMail            10      1_firma
575788    ComputerSalg A/S     10      2_firma
713000    CompuMail            10      2_firma
713000    Proshop.dk           10      2_firma
713000    ComputerSalg A/S     10      3_firma
```

Comment: There are actually 10 sets of firma and pris fields, not just 3.

Comment: Then just repeat it for 10 sets and extend your untion query. Still the best way I think. You dont need a pivot or crosstab (lot of memery waste), just plain and simple select queries. And on top you have a decent data model in the end (if you join `ItemID` you got all `Firm` results with the same `ItemID`).

Comment: You forgot FROM clause. I tested this approach and output is not 3 pairs of fields.

Comment: You are right I forgot the `From`. You shouldnt copy paste the code, you should get the idea behind it. And I think you can create the the queryíes in the designer. Drag and drop the fields down and filter the one column to `<> Null`.

Comment: I still don't see how it will get the 3 pairs of fields OP requires without CROSSTAB. Have you reviewed my answer?

Comment: I definitely understand how to get to that point but it's not what the OP wants.

Comment: Thats why it is called an alternative approach, so he can decide wheather it suits him or not. Answering question can also be seen as teaching responsibility. It happens often that an answer which is not 100% like the op wants it (maybe he doesnt know better, to less experience, ...) is the better solution and the op is happy with it.